# Which font is used for Dr. Kuldip Kular's election ad?

Tags: font-identification, serif

[image: Kuldip Kular election ad]

I'm a newbie and can't figure out what font is being used in the image below. Please help.

Comment: You can use [Whatthefont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) and use an image to help find fonts

Comment: Thanks SatursEye...I tried that but it didn't work for my image for some reason.

Comment: Yes I noticed that too, I had to screenshot the image and upload it that way

Comment: I believe you have 3 fonts in use there. The gray text appears to be possibly Myriad.

Answer (score 2):

"Kular" is a gothic of some kind. Not sure exactly which, though he does use [Oswald](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/oswald) on his [website](http://www.votekular.ca/) and it's a pretty close match:

[image: Oswald screenshot]

Some alternatives are [Franklin Gothic Extra Condensed](http://www.fonts.com/font/linotype/franklin-gothic/extra-condensed):

[image: Franklin Gothic Condensed screenshot]

and [League Gothic](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/League-Gothic):

[image: League Gothic screenshot]

For the "Passionate about life" bit, you could try [Open Sans](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans). The characters might be a touch different but it might be close enough to suit your needs:

[image: Open Sans screenshot]

"Dr. Kuldip" might be [Questrial](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/questrial) (but Questrial isn't "Elect", for sure):

[image: Questrial screenshot]

"Elect" is tough to tell, but it might just be your typical Arial/Helvetica.

Answer (score 2):

**Kuler** is [Franklin Gothic Extra Condensed](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/franklin-gothic/). Note the subtle changes in thickness which indicate it is not a DIN-style font (for example, in the bowl of U):

[image: Franklin Gothic Extra Cond]

**Elect** is plain ol' Helvetica.

**Dr. Kuldip** is [Gotham](http://www.typography.com/fonts/gotham/inside/gotham)

[image: Hoefler Gotham]

**Passionate** etc is too small to identify conclusively.

Comment: That gothic is tough to nail down...look at the top of the "A" in Franklin Gothic - it isn't quite right. Could have been modified I suppose, but given the overall quality of the graphic I doubt it...

Comment: There are various different cuts of Franklin Gothic (for example, the arms of my U are very similar in width; some aren't) but the top of the A is a problem with that identification.

Answer (score 0):

The `Kuler` looks like [DIN Next Pro Condensed Bold](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/din-next/pro-condensed-bold/)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Any idea what the smaller font above is "Elect Dr. Kular" ?

Comment: @user23747 It's not picking up the smaller font too well I'm afraid.

Comment: @user23747 if you found my answer helpful you can up-vote it or even vote it as the correct answer.